# Canned air spray got liquid all over my PSU

Tags: power-supply, cleaning, maintenance

Wanted to remove dust from my PC with a canned air aerozol "duster". Tried it a couple of times without applying to my computer and all seemed fine.

Decided to go for the PSU first: since it's a the bottom I tilted the aerozol to the side and it sprayed liquid all over my PSU. (I didn't know that tilting it sprays liquid). Now I [know](https://superuser.com/questions/485088/air-duster-sprays-are-they-safe-for-hardware).

The liquid seemed to evaporate really fast but I'm still freaking out a little bit before turning it on.

1) What is the amount of time to wait in this situation before it's safe to turn the PC on?

2) What is the worst case scenario from this situation?

3) Any random advice/reassurance?

Comment: Possible dupe of [How to clean/what to do about getting liquid form of compressed air cleaner on computer equipment?](https://superuser.com/q/786210)

Comment: Just wait for it to dry. If you see any residue that's stuck, use alcohol to remove it. You probably won't need to though.